# JavaScript check if class contains one or more values of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, contains

i have an array like this :

```
var testVar = {
    "test": [{
        "atn": "xxx1",
        "price": 9999999
    }, {
        "atn": "xxx2",
        "price": 9999999
    }]
};
```

and html like :

```
<span class="testClass">xxx1</span>
<span class="testClass">yyy</span>
<span class="testClass">pppp</span>
```

now i want to check if one or more of the .testClass contains at least one of the value in this array. and then count the value of it.

I tried it with jquery (inArray(), contains, for each and so one ... but i don't get the point ^^).

Thx for everyone who has an idea =)

Comment: Could you show the code you tried?

Comment: You don't have an array, you have objects with key/value pairs, just stuffing it into `inArray` won't do much good

Comment: do it the other way round. All the data in js, then update the html based on button clikcs / other inputs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick answer

```js
var testVar = {
    "test": [{
        "atn": "xxx1",
        "price": 9999999
    }, {
        "atn": "xxx2",
        "price": 9999999
    }]
};

var testClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("testClass");

[].forEach.call(testClasses, function (testClass) {
  for (var i = 0; i < testVar.test.length; i++) {
    if (testVar.test[i]["atn"] === testClass.innerHTML) {
      console.log("found value = " + testClass.innerHTML);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<span class="testClass">xxx1</span>
<span class="testClass">yyy</span>
<span class="testClass">pppp</span>
```

Comment: maaaaaannnnyyy thanks !!!
I think I can work with this ...

@adeneo thx yes that right than. I check this on w3school "they" told me (more or less) that would be an array. I have to learn the names i know :/